# Wordlist generator with a certain pattern

Tags: passwords, crunch, wordlist

I am trying to generate a wordlist. I am using *crunch* but I am stuck at defining the pattern I want the words to be generated. For example, I want to define a rule such as this:

Password: `Ameri948 ca#`

Words: `[A|a]meri[\d\d\d][space|no space][C|c]a[space|*|#]`

Which means, I know the structure of the password and the exact length (here the space or no space plays a role), but not the exact combinations, e.g. the first character is for sure an **A** but I don't know whether it is a capital **A** or a lowercase one. And another problem is spaces, to get the password to a certain length, which I know, I tried some sort of padding with spaces in between words.

Can a pattern like this be defined in crunch? Or would you suggest just coding it?

Comment: I edited your pattern to be a little more `regex` in feel to be a little more readable

Comment: Your pattern is too complex for most generators. This is the type of thing to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a tool like [Generex](https://github.com/mifmif/Generex) to generate strings out of a regular expression. I think your case would be:

```
[Aa]meri\d{3}\s?[Cc]a\s{0,4}#
```

I limited the latter space to max 4 so the regex would be able to terminate. There are some online tools available that do this too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sets from crunch. However, there are only 4:

```
@ , % ^
```

Depending on the number of spaces, you can write them down directly. For

`[A|a]meri[\d\d\d][space|no space][C|c]a[space|*|#]`

this could be:

```
crunch 12 12 aA cC + \ *# -t '@meri%%% ,a^' -o list && crunch 11 11 aA cC + \ *# -t '@meri%%%,a^' >> list
```

Here I used the 3rd default set (defined with +) what are numbers.

Or you could put a bash script around it, e.g. using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076395/how-to-add-x-number-of-leading-spaces-in- a-string-using-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076395/how-to-add-x-number-of-leading-spaces-in-a-string-using-bash) if you want to loop over some spaces:

```
for space_amount in {1..3}; do spaces=$(printf "%*s" $space_amount);crunch $(expr 11 + $space_amount) $(expr 11 + $space_amount) aA cC + \ *# -t "@meri%%%$spaces,a^" >> list; done
```

If you need more sets I would use Generex as recommended from ysf or start expanding it programmatically.